# Python function squaring

Tags: python

I need to accept a list of numbers and make that numbers squared. Based on this. I thought that the code I was writing was correct but it didn't show any output.

Can you guys help me figure out what's wrong?

```
def square(num_list):

    Accepts a list of numbers, and returns a list of the same numbers squared.
    e.g. [1, 2, 3] -> [1, 4, 9]
    """

    return squared_list  


#MYCODE

def squared(list):

    squared_list = [ ]

    for i in squared_list:

        squared_list.append(i ** 2)

    return squared_list
```

Comment: `for i in squared_list:` ? squared_list is empty. you wanted `for i in list`. Also, avoid using the name `list` for your variable name, it shadows the builtin.

Comment: You're iterating over an empty list. Also don't use `list` as variable name

Answer (score 2):

```
def squared(list):
    squared_list = []
    for i in list: #<---- you are itterating over empty list squared_list
        squared_list.append(i**2)
    return squared_list

print (squared([1,2,3]))
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use list comprehension

```
def square(input_list):
     square_list =[ number**2 for number in input_list]
     return square_list
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in squared_list:`

^That's your problem, you go through the empty list, not the one with numbers.

So it should be:

```
def squared(list):
    squared_list = [ ]
    for i in list: # changed here
        squared_list.append(i ** 2)

    return squared_list
```

Also, I'd recommend not using the name `list` - it shadows the buildin class name. It's ok in a function (you shadow it only in that function) but still a bad practice.

There's also a much shorter version using list comprehension: `return [i**2 for i in list]`